# hover over a list item not taking the full height of the header

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Hello everyone I am using CSS grid and flexbox together to create a header. But I am facing a problem which is on the social class there are three social icons(Facebook, Twitter, Instagram) when hovering over them I want the background color to be blue and take the full height of the header. At the moment it's only taking the height of the flexbox I guess. How can I fix that and what's the reason behind that? can anyone help me with this?

I want the hover effect to be like this[image]
But i am getting this: [image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<header class="head-container">
        <div class="head-info">
            <div class="contact">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Email:
                        <a href="#"> support@assignmentClassMate.com</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Phone: +61-730-407-305</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="social">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><b>My Account</b> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Follow Us On:
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

This is my CSS file:

```
.head-container {
  padding: 15px 100px;
  background-color: #9e0b0b;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.head-container .head-info {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto auto;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.head-container .head-info .contact ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.head-container .head-info .social {
  height: 100%;
}

.head-container .head-info .social ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: end;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.head-container .head-info .social ul li a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.head-container .head-info .social ul li a i {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.head-container .head-info .social ul li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.head-container li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.head-container a {
  color: #fff;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you gave your `.head-container` a padding. Through this padding it's not possible to overlap the background-color of your `.head-container` from any inner element.

Instead of giving the `.head-container` a padding, you could easily give your elements inside the container a padding.
When you remove the padding of `.head-container` and `.head-container .head-info` and adding some to `.head-container .head-info .social ul li a`

```
.head-container .head-info .social ul li a {
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You get the result which you are looking for.

(Note, it's important to set the display to block, else the padding would not effect correctly to the element)

Of couse you have to give `.head-container .head-info .contact` some padding or use some flexbox properties so the text will be centered.

To receive some space between the right and left border/edge, you can give the `.head-container` or `.head-info` some padding like this: `padding: 0px, 100px, 0px 100px;`. It's important that you don't set any padding to the top or bottom at these classes. Else you will receive the same problem as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not style the actual `a` tag, and instead give the background color to the `li` element. You'll need to add the following styles.

```
.head-container .head-info .social ul li {
  height: 100%;
}

.head-container .head-info .social ul li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

If you just want the hover functionality for the icons, then you could do:

```
.head-container .head-info .social ul li.icon {
  height: 100%;
}

.head-container .head-info .social ul li.icon:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

<div class="social">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><b>My Account</b> </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      Follow Us On:
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If that doesn't answer your question, let me know.

Comment: I have edited my question. could you please check? Your solution is not working the way I wanted.